# C++ pthread_mutex does not work as expected on db access

Tags: c++, database, pthreads, mutex

I am quite new to the usage of mutexes(only weak theoretical knowledge given by old university courses). I am working to an issue regarding db access. I'll now explain my situation in order to let you understand better the situation:

there exist different entities (each one spawned on a different thread) called A, B and C, that access to the database(sqlite3 database) both in read/write through a singleton class called DB_Manager( having so a centralized class that manages all the functions). 
Because of I am working on a software that runs on a custom hw, I am not able to use C++11 (that I know the singleton pattern is made thread-safe by default). My issue is that I cannot avoid concurrency between the three entities A, B and C.

I've declared the mutex as a member variable of DB_Manager class, with getter method. From A, B and C, whenever comes a critical region of code, I'll do something like this:

```
lock_db=DB_Manager->getMutex();

while(pthread_mutex_lock(lock_db) < 0)
{
  //loop in order to wait the release of the mutex because has being locked by someone else
      }
 //here, the mutex has been succesfully locked

 //HERE RESIDE THE CRITICAL PART OF CODE

pthread_mutex_unlock(lock_db);   //release the mutex
```

This behaviour is replicated in each critical part of code of both A, B and C entities.

Once running, each does one loop of the while (I know this because I've placed log print inside the while loops) and then all is blocked. I don't know what is going on. I tried all different possibilities found on the web.

I admit that I am new to concurrent programming so I could be missing something.

Comment: Use the C++ standard thread API.

Comment: I cannot use it.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thank you for the hint! I know that it's always my fault, but I posted here to have help from you guys, not to be downvoted/bullied! :D

Comment: @panc_fab You can use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print the error message. Perhaps it would give you any hints. Also, show us more of your code. How did you initialized the field, which is returned by getMutex() method?

Comment: Your while (pthread_mutex_lock()) loop should not be needed unless you have done something very odd - pthread_mutex_lock() is a blocking call. If pthread_mutex_lock() returns < 0, you are normally in a huge pile of awful trouble (Note that normally, pthread_mutex_lock returns a positive value on error, and zero on success).Save the return value when this happens and tell us the results (the return value is an errno value, use e.g. strerror() to convert it to a string.)  You might not have properly initialized the mutex, or you have copied your mutex (which you are not allowed to do) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by @nos, I removed the while over the mutex lock, and simply all gone ok! 
Newbie error... but fortunately fixed! 
Thank you @nos!